# Tabs with different colors

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

If I create a list of tabs, the aesthetics of which is given by a Container to which I assign a Color, can I make the color of this Container dynamic with an if-else so that each tab has the different color according to the color chosen by the user, or will the list appear to me with all the tabs in the same color?

Here an example of the tab:

```
Container buildTaskCard(Task personModel, [Color color = Colors.white]) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 5, 20, 5),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 10, 10, 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color, //Colore dinamico
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ....
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

As in the example below, you can collect the colors in one list and then give them index by index:

```
class TabPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TabPage> createState() => _TabPageState();
}

class _TabPageState extends State<TabPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  _TabPageState({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: personModels.length, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: TabBar(
      controller: _tabController,
        tabs: List<Widget>.generate(personModels.length,
            (index) => buildTaskCard(personModels[index], colors[index])),
      ),
    );
  }

  final List<Color> colors = [...]; // your colors
  final List<Task> personModels = [...]; // your personmodels

  Container buildTaskCard(Task personModel, [Color color = Colors.white]) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 5, 20, 5),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 10, 10, 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color, //Colore dinamico
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ....
    );
  }
}
```